# Azure API Management Sign Up Stuck In Process

Tags: azure-api-management

I'm using Azure API Management and I have a user who tried to sign up but never got the "validation" email.  Let's just assume the email is not recoverable.  Unfortunately, I have no way to reset that user's email address.  The API Management framework knows that the email already exists but I have no visibility to that user's profile until they validate the account.  At that point I can manage their account but, until then, they are in-limbo.

If the user tries to re-sign up or even if I send an invite, we get an error that says.  "Email already exist"

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

The confirmation request will expire in 2 days, so if the user tries again after 2 days, the "email already exist" error should go away.

Meanwhile, we are currently working on a feature to allow Admins to delete unconfirmed users from the Management Console.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to allowing admins to remove unconfirmed users we added the ability for users to re-send confirmation email.